# Handling Null Values in Linq in Select Block

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am facing any issue while selecting values in Linq as while selecting there may be null values but I cannot give the condition to remove that row if the value is `null`.

Below is the Linq query I am using. Can you please help me with this?

```
var value = (from data in dt.AsEnumerable()
select new{
    Test1 = data.Field<decimal>("Test1"),Test2 = data.Field<decimal?>("Test2") --Value is null
    ,Test3 = data.Field<decimal?>("Test3") --Value is null
    ,Test4 = data.Field<decimal?>("Test4") --Value is null
    ,Test5 = data.Field<DateTime?>("Test5")--Value is null });
```

I need to handle `null` in select block and not in where condition.

I am getting below error while executing the query:

> Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a
>   nullable type

Comment: Handle how? This `select` clause will work just fine with nulls. What do you want to produce? `Field<>`will return the actual value so if you want to *replace* nulls, just add `?? someDefault`, eg `?? 0m`

Comment: Did you mean to Remove not Remote? Please review your spelling and grammar.

Comment: I am getting below error whil executing the query                                          
Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.DateTime'. Please use a nullable type.

Comment: Not sure, but try changing Test5 line to: Test5 = (data.Field<object>("Test5") == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : data.Field<DateTime?>("Test5"))

Comment: Your code shows `DateTime?` as the cast and that should handle `null` fine. Are you sure this code is exactly like the code giving you the error?